# Remove Url Parameter Wordpress

Tags: plugins, search, codex

I have problem with search in WordPress. I want to remove the "s" parameter in the URL. This is my URL:

`www.example.com?post_type=tour&s=&tour_location=70&tour_types=116&tour_month=144&tour_year=66`

I want the URL to look like:

`www.example.com?post_type=tour&tour_location=70&tour_types=116&tour_month=144&tour_year=66`

How do I need to modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

The "s" variable parameter is for the search term and is used when there's a search on a WordPress site.

If you have a form that users are filling out, there should be code similar to:

`<input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />`

Delete that input tag and the "s" will disappear.

Comment: but when i'm delete "s" on URL. dislpay page not found? from www.example.com?post_type=tour&s=&tour_location=70&tour_type‌​s=116&tour_month=144‌​&tour_year=66 become www.example.com?post_type=tour&tour_location=70&tour_types=1‌​16&tour_month=144&to‌​ur_year=66 –